# SSRS Hyperlink to tab on the same spreadsheet

Tags: reporting-services, hyperlink, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have two set of data on 2 tabs of the same report in SSRS

1. Employee Name, Employee Number, Department ID
2. Employee Number, Department ID, Department Details

I am trying to create a hyperlink on Department ID of tab 1 to link to Department ID of tab 2 of the same report.

This report should be rendered to excel spreadsheet, where the hyperlink from tab 1 row 1 should take you to details in tab 2 row 2(mapped by department ID)

I tried using the Go to Report feature on SSRS but I don't know how to do it for different sheet on the same report.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is supported when rendered to Excel but look at bookmarks.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-a-bookmark-to-a-report-report-builder-and-ssrs

Comment: Yes I tried bookmarks which just takes me to the specified worksheet. Is there a way to map the department ID and make the link take us to the specific ID row?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, I've only ever used bookmarks to navigate to a page/group.